# Invalid pointer - Memory - Qt

Tags: c++, qt, memory, gdb, valgrind

I'd like to tell you a strange problem I have with my Qt application.

I have two windows: the first is a QMainWindow, the second a QDialog derived class. The QMainWindow shows the QDialog one, which has a form and a QPushButton in order to use QFileDialog::getOpenFileName.

When I run my app for the first time (after system boot) I have a memory problem:

```
*** Error in `/home/nico/Documents/Projets_QtCreator/build-utilitaireTwsGraph-Kit_test-Debug/utilitaireTwsGraph': free(): invalid pointer: 0x000000000090cd40 ***
```

To reproduce this problem I have to restart my system, so I think it's a typically corrupted memory error. I did some investigations:

First, I tried to find the incriminated line using gdb. It told me:

```
Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
0x00007ffff63ac037 in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:56
56  ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type.
```

The stack trace showed:

```
(gdb) where
#0  0x00007ffff63ac037 in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:56
#1  0x00007ffff63af698 in __GI_abort () at abort.c:90
#2  0x00007ffff63e95ab in __libc_message (do_abort=do_abort@entry=2, fmt=fmt@entry=0x7ffff64fc860 "*** Error in `%s': %s: 0x%s ***\n")
    at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/libc_fatal.c:199
#3  0x00007ffff63f5a46 in malloc_printerr (ptr=0x90cd40, str=0x7ffff64f8825 "free(): invalid pointer", action=3) at malloc.c:4902
#4  _int_free (av=<optimized out>, p=0x90cd30, have_lock=0) at malloc.c:3758
#5  0x00007fffeea21d76 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0
#6  0x00007ffff50f6538 in g_object_unref () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0
#7  0x00007fffeea0f21b in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0
#8  0x00007fffeea13584 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0
#9  0x00007ffff50f6538 in g_object_unref () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0
#10 0x00007fffee9b59ea in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0
#11 0x00007fffee9eaf5f in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0
#12 0x00007ffff50f155e in g_closure_invoke () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0
#13 0x00007ffff51030e4 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0
#14 0x00007ffff510ad11 in g_signal_emit_valist () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0
#15 0x00007ffff510af92 in g_signal_emit () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0
#16 0x00007fffeea8f580 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0
#17 0x00007ffff50f7640 in g_object_run_dispose () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0
#18 0x00007fffee9b59ea in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0
#19 0x00007fffee9eaf5f in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0
#20 0x00007ffff50f155e in g_closure_invoke () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0
#21 0x00007ffff51030e4 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0
#22 0x00007ffff510ad11 in g_signal_emit_valist () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0
#23 0x00007ffff510af92 in g_signal_emit () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0
#24 0x00007fffeea8f580 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0
#25 0x00007ffff50f7640 in g_object_run_dispose () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0
#26 0x00007fffee9eaf5f in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0
#27 0x00007ffff50f1620 in g_closure_invoke () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0
#28 0x00007ffff51030e4 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0
#29 0x00007ffff510ad11 in g_signal_emit_valist () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0
#30 0x00007ffff510af92 in g_signal_emit () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0
#31 0x00007fffeea8f580 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0
#32 0x00007ffff50f7640 in g_object_run_dispose () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0
#33 0x00007ffff7684879 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtGui.so.4
#34 0x00007ffff77c537a in QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(QWidget*, QString const&, QString const&, QString const&, QString*, QFlags<QFileDialog::Option>) ()
   from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtGui.so.4
#35 0x0000000000409277 in FenetreSelectionStatusMonitor::selectionnerStatusMonitor (this=0x825710)
    at ../utilitaireTwsGraph/dev/src/vue/fenetreSelectionStatusMonitor.cpp:89
```

So I guessed that problem is in my getOpenFileName call.

Then, I remove the modality property of my QDialog (had no effects), I used valgrind but it didn't helped me:

```
 Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==2237==    at 0x4C2BA6C: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==2237==    by 0xE194D75: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0.2400.17)
==2237==    by 0x78F3537: g_object_unref (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.3600.0)
==2237==    by 0xE18221A: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0.2400.17)
==2237==    by 0xE186583: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0.2400.17)
==2237==    by 0x78F3537: g_object_unref (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.3600.0)
==2237==    by 0xE1289E9: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0.2400.17)
==2237==    by 0xE15DF5E: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0.2400.17)
==2237==    by 0x78EE55D: g_closure_invoke (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.3600.0)
==2237==    by 0x79000E3: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.3600.0)
==2237==    by 0x7907D10: g_signal_emit_valist (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.3600.0)
==2237==    by 0x7907F91: g_signal_emit (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.3600.0)
==2237==  Address 0x155066d0 is 720 bytes inside a block of size 1,008 alloc'd
==2237==    at 0x4C2A896: memalign (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==2237==    by 0x4C2A987: posix_memalign (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==2237==    by 0x6F22A07: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.3600.0)
==2237==    by 0x6F6C3EB: g_slice_alloc (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.3600.0)
==2237==    by 0x6F6C445: g_slice_alloc0 (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.3600.0)
==2237==    by 0x790E8C4: g_type_create_instance (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.3600.0)
==2237==    by 0x78F9A4B: g_param_spec_internal (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.3600.0)
==2237==    by 0x78FDA11: g_param_spec_object (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.3600.0)
==2237==    by 0xD98D4CB: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0.3600.0)
==2237==    by 0x790C955: g_type_class_ref (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.3600.0)
==2237==    by 0x78F535C: g_object_new_valist (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.3600.0)
==2237==    by 0x78F5803: g_object_new (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.3600.0)
==2237==
```

When I don't use native dialog, I don't have this problem. So I think it could be a system dependency or package error, but I have an other application which uses GetOpenFileName (quite same call), I can compile it and it works.

The GetOpenFileName call is in a Qt Slot:

```
void FenetreSelectionStatusMonitor::selectionnerStatusMonitor() {
    QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, tr("Fichier descriptif du status monitor"), "/home",tr("Lst (*.lst)"));
}
```

The header file (I removed useless declarations):

```
#ifndef FENETRE_SELECTION_STATUS_MONITOR
#define FENETRE_SELECTION_STATUS_MONITOR

#include <QFileDialog>

class FenetreSelectionStatusMonitor : public QDialog {
    Q_OBJECT
    public:
        FenetreSelectionStatusMonitor(int hauteur, int largeur, QWidget* parent);

    private slots:
        void selectionnerStatusMonitor();
};

#endif // FENETRE_SELECTION_STATUS_MONITOR
```

I think I'll try to reinstall my qt packages because I don't have any ideas now. I checked the calling arguments, but without finding anything. I'm asking me questions because of the lack of stability of my program. And even if I had no problems, I don't know how to prove that my program will not crash and has no memory leack (valgrind with libraries is hard to use),it's quite desesperating !

Thanks a lot for reading this post, I hope you can help me :)

EDIT: I bought a new project, just having a simple QMainWindow calling a QDialog which calls GetOpenFileName. I have exactly the same problem.

This new project has 2 classes and a main:

main.cpp:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include "mainWindowTest.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    QApplication app(argc,argv);
    MainWindowTest window;
    window.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

mainWindowTest.h:

```
#ifndef MAIN_WINDOW_TEST_H
#define MAIN_WINDOW_TEST_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <QPushButton>
#include "dialogTest.h"

class MainWindowTest : public QMainWindow {
    Q_OBJECT

    public:
        MainWindowTest();

    private slots:
        void openDialog();
};

#endif //MAIN_WINDOW_TEST_H
```

dialogTest.h:

```
#ifndef DIALOG_TEST_H
#define DIALOG_TEST_H

#include <QDialog>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QFileDialog>

class DialogTest : public QDialog {
    Q_OBJECT

    public:
        DialogTest();

    private slots:
        void openFile();
};

#endif //DIALOG_TEST_H
```

mainWindowTest.cpp

```
#include "mainWindowTest.h"

MainWindowTest::MainWindowTest() {
    setMinimumSize(200,200);

    QWidget* widget = new QWidget();
    QHBoxLayout* layout = new QHBoxLayout();
    QPushButton* btnOpen = new QPushButton("Open dialog");
    connect(btnOpen, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(openDialog()));
    layout->addWidget(btnOpen);

    widget->setLayout(layout);
    setCentralWidget(widget);
}

void MainWindowTest::openDialog() {
    DialogTest dialog;
    dialog.exec();
}
```

dialogTest.cpp

```
#include "dialogTest.h"

DialogTest::DialogTest() {
    QHBoxLayout* layout = new QHBoxLayout();
    QPushButton* btnOpen = new QPushButton("Open file");
    connect(btnOpen, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(openFile()));
    layout->addWidget(btnOpen);

    setLayout(layout);
}

void DialogTest::openFile() {
    QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, tr("Fichier descriptif du status monitor"), "/home", tr("Lst (*.lst)"));
}
```

Comment: I do remember a QT-Bug regarding the FileDialog where it crashes only in debugger, not in release.

Comment: I switched to release mode but the problem still occurs ;)

Comment: I realized that the problem occurs only when I'm selecting a file in a non-mounted disk (so it becomes monted). I don't understand why it happens for all my qt apps, with qt creator or another programm (gedit, for example) it works. And I don't know why qtcreator needs sudo password whereas my app's and gedit don't have to. Have you any  idea ?